# Angular Exposing a function from modal instance?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I used this tidbit of code from another Stack Overflow question

```
$modalInstance.opened.then(function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

In the alert section I want to call a function that resides on the modalcontroller. How can I do that?

My modal call is below

```
this.OpenMyModal = function(){

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: 'static',
        templateUrl: 'MyAddress/MyController/MyMethod',
        controller: 'modalController',         
        resolve: {              
           myTemplateUrl: function(){                   
               return myTemplateUrl;
                }           
        }
    });

modalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
      /*modalcontroller function to call goes here;*/
    modalController.SearchClick();
    });

  return modalInstance.result.then(function (returnedInput) {
        return returnedInput;
    }, function () {
        // dismissed with cancel button
        return "";
    })
}
```

Currently the modal controller is used for searching. There is a onclick function that is in the modal controller that I want to call. The function on the controller is called

```
$scope.SearchClick = function()
{
$scope.Search();
}
```

If I call the click function when the controller is initialized it will break functionality for other items that use this same controller.

I just need the ability to call this simple function when I call this controller.

Comment: Can you provide more context? It's unclear where your first bit of code resides. Even better would be a plunkr/fiddle

Comment: Why would you call it in the .rendered rather than just call it directly from within modalController when it is instantiated?  Some context would be helpful in understanding what you're doing.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Even with the update I don't understand the context of the second part of your  code.  Is this inside a separate service? If so, where is this code called from? A plunkr would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iK3Zx3rWBu1VrAZGxBpi)

In this plunker I call a function inside the modal in two ways.

In the first way I call the modal function just after the modal appear.
In the second way I call the modal function using an event. I fire this event from my controller and in the modal controller I have a listener waiting for this event.

**Method 1:**
In your modal controller create a method "initialize" (just an example).

```
function initialize() {
    // Here you can call your function

    console.log('Method 1, Call your function now!');
    $scope.myFunctionInsideModal();
}
```

And call this method in the modal controller

```
initialize(); // Initialize stuff
```

**Method 2:** 
Fire an event from your controller

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', 'any data');
```

And put a listener in your modal controller:

```
$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function(event, data) {
    // Here you can call your function

    console.log('Method 2, Call your function now! ');
    $scope.myFunctionInsideModal();
})
```

Hope it helps. 
 See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iK3Zx3rWBu1VrAZGxBpi)  for more details and a working example.